# Using Pandas, Could i detect wrong element in a fixed column and return that value?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am new to Pandas. My goal is to detect the wrong element  in a fixed column  and return that  row value 
Here is the sample scenario

[image]

45 dollar is the wrong element in the country column. so i want to detect this value and return the row number(if possible) in my program. My first thought was to create a list and match with this or do i need to search NLP solution here. Kindly help me to solve it out

Comment: Sounds like you will need to first determine how an entry will be deemed "wrong". A list (or set) of ALL countries would certainly work to check if values are in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answer depends on how you want to validate going forward.  Are you looking for any value containing a number or any value that is not an expected country?

Comment: any value that is not expected country in this case :) so  45dollar will be my desired invalid  data which i want to detect

Answer (score 0):

Install [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) and import it, post that execute the below code:

```
[i.name for i in list(pycountry.countries)]
```

this gives you a list of all the countries.

Post this check which countries fall in the list and negate them to get a list of which rows doesnot fall under countries list.

```
 import pycountry
 df.Country[~df.Country.isin([i.name for i in list(pycountry.countries)])]
```

**Note:** This might not work if the country names are not standardly maintained in the column name.